# PRISM Part Creation Policy NonShared/Shared with MEF

Tags: wpf, prism, mef, containers, service-locator

I have set `PartCreationPolicy.NonShared` for my view, but for some specific users I can use the `CreationPolicy.Shared` (For performance improvement), I am not sure if it can be done or not. as I am using `ServiceLocator` to get instances of Views. like

`view = ServiceLocator.GetInstance<MyUserControl>("view_contract");`

What could be the best solution for this. I have searched on Google for it, I have found some solutions with `CompositionContainer.GetExports`, but

1- I am unable to get `CompositionContainer` instance in my ViewModel.

2- [In This Post](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20the%20Composition%20Container) , It is written under **GetExport** that

> Successive invocation of the export's Value will return the same
>   instance, regardless of whether the part has a Shared or Non-Shared
>   lifetime.

Please could any one suggest the best solution and some example code snippet for it?

Comment: Have a look at ExportFactory (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/17/exportfactory-amp-lt-t-amp-gt-in-mef-2-alok.aspx). Instead of GetExport which returns a Lazy<T> use ExportFactory<T>.

Comment: Thanks @PanosRontogiannis, but how can I get `CompositionContainer` in my ViewModel? as in point 1?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you have some "business logic" to distinguish between shared and non-shared views (e.g. depending on the type of users). I think this should not be handled in your DI container...

If you want to achief this with the "prism-style" then you could use the prism `INavigationAware` interface in your ViewModels: the view and viewModel are non-shared and you activate/construct it via navigation (works perfectly with MEF). Put your business logic for "shared"/"non-shared" into the "IsNavigationTarget" method. Prism will call this method automatically and create a new view instance only if needed.

Here is some code:

The view (don't forget the view name as navigation target!):

```
[Export(Constants.ViewNames.MyFirstViewName)] // The Export Name is only needed for Prism's view navigation.
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)] // there may be multiple instances of the view => NO singleton!!
public partial class MyFirstView
{ ... }
```

The ViewModel:

```
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)] 
    [Export]
    public class MyFirstViewModel: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.INavigationAware
    {
       #region IINavigationAware
        // this interface ships with Prism4 and is used here because there may be multiple instances of the view
        // and all this instances can be targets of navigation.

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when [navigated to].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="navigationContext">The navigation context.</param>
        public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {                    
            ...
        }

        /// <summary>        
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnActivate()
        {
            ...
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is navigation target] [the specified navigation context].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="navigationContext">The navigation context.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if [is navigation target] [the specified navigation context]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        public override bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            // use any kind of busines logic to find out if you need a new view instance or the existing one. You can also find any specific target view using the navigationContext...
            bool thereCanBeOnlyOneInstance = ...
            return thereCanBeOnlyOneInstance;
        }    

        #endregion
}
```

Comment: COuld you please share some code example? what need to be done in `IsNavigationTarget`

Comment: I am using `IRegionManager` to add a view to `Region`, and using `ServiceLocator.GetInstance<T>()` to get the instance to view, `Service Locator` gets the instance using `PartCreationPolicy`, how can I control this behavior from the above code?

Comment: The RegionManager will do this work for you. Simply call "RequestNavigate" and you will NOT have to find the view/viewModel instance for yourself:
IRegionManager regionManager = ...;
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion",                              new Uri("InboxView", UriKind.Relative));

See [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx) here...

Comment: but it will use `PartCreationPolicy` attribute, which I don't want for this case.